# Why does my form with two buttons does not submit the form?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm doing a form that calculates distance between two addresses (with google matrix API), and when i submit the form, it only showing me distance and the duration between the two points (on the 2 input submit).
I'd like to have the first input to be the one that show the duration and km between the two points and the second input to send these information to the file "toreservationRequest.php" that will put in the database.

Here is a picture to have a better idea:

[image: form with two buttons]

```
<form action="reservationRequest.php" method="POST" class="container form-control text-center" id="distance_form">
<a href="book.php" class="closeJquery float-right"><img src="img/backspace-arrow.png"></a>
    <h3>Réservation standard :</h3><br>
    <label>Date de départ</label>
    <input type="text" id="datepickerGo" name="datepickerGo" class="datepicker form-control" name="go" placeholder="Selectionez une date"><br>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group"><label>Départ: </label> <input class="form-control" id="from_places" placeholder="Entrez l'adresse de départ" name="from_places"/> <input id="origin" name="origin" required="" type="hidden" /></div>

    <div class="form-group"><label>Arrivée: </label> <input class="form-control" id="to_places" placeholder="Entrez l'adresse d'arrivée" name="to_places"/> <input id="destination" name="destination" required="" type="hidden" /></div>
    <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" id="calculate" value="Calculer la durée et la distance en KM" />

    <div id="result"></div>

    <br>
    <label>Remarque</label>
    <input type="text" name="note" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez une remarque">
    <br>
    <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
      Prix TTC : 50€
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark form-control">

</form>
```

The javascript code :

```
$(function() {

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var from_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('from_places'));
        var to_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('to_places'));

        google.maps.event.addListener(from_places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var from_place = from_places.getPlace();
            var from_address = from_place.formatted_address;
            $('#origin').val(from_address);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(to_places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var to_place = to_places.getPlace();
            var to_address = to_place.formatted_address;
            $('#destination').val(to_address);
        });

    });

    // calcule la distance entre point A et point B:
    function calculateDistance() {
        var origin = $('#origin').val();
        var destination = $('#destination').val();
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
                origins: [origin],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.metric, // KM et métres
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, callback);
    }

    // renvoie la distance:
    function callback(response, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            $('#result').html(err);
        } else {
            var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
            var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
            if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                $('#result').html("erreur");
            } else {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
                console.log(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
                var distance_in_kilo = distance.value / 1000;

                var duration_text = duration.text;
                var duration_value = duration.value;

                $('#in_kilo').text(distance_in_kilo.toFixed(2));
                $('#duration_text').text(duration_text);
                $('#duration_value').text(duration_value);
                $('#from').text(origin);
                $('#to').text(destination);

                console.log(distance_in_kilo);
                console.log(duration_text);

                $("#result").html("<label>Distance (KM): </label><p id='distance'>"+ distance_in_kilo +"</p> <label>Durée : </label><p id='duree'>"+ duration_text +"<p>");
            }
        }
    }

    // affiche resultat
    $('#distance_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        calculateDistance();

        var strFromPlaces = $('#from_places').val();
        var strToPlaces = $('#to_places').val();

        if(strFromPlaces.length == '' || strToPlaces.length ==''){
            alert('Veuillez renseigner tout les champs');
        }

    });


});
```

Thanks a lot in advance for helping.

Comment: Try console.log in the submit to see if it even fires. it's always a good place to start. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `e.preventDefault();` on submit

Use this for expected result:

```
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        calculateDistance();

        var strFromPlaces = $('#from_places').val();
        var strToPlaces = $('#to_places').val();

        if(strFromPlaces.length == '' || strToPlaces.length ==''){
            alert('Veuillez renseigner tout les champs');
        }
        $("#distance_form").submit();

    });
```

Comment: when I remove it, it submit the form without showing the duration and distance

Comment: add another button that will do that and add a `click` event on it

Comment: You need to have _something_ subumitting the code, try adding `$("#distance_form").submit();` at the end of the section titled `affiche resultat`.

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault();` will prevent the form from submitting. Which is good. But after you've done your calculations, you'll need to submit the form. So add `$("#distance_form").submit();` and the form data will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I've find the solution :
i've put and id "calculate" on the first input submit and an id "submit2" on the second submit.

on the form I removed the action="reservationRequest.php"

and on the second submit i've put in attribute : `formaction="reservationRequest.php"`

and for the javascript :

```
$('#calculate').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        calculateDistance();
}
```